# how can I insert new rows from table 2 in table 1 with the corresponding date?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables that I want to join using a date field:

- Table 1: there're multiple records for each date
- Table 2: there's only 1 record for each date

How can I update records in Table 1 with fields from Table 2 corresponding the date. Here's an example:

```
table1 
column1    column2   column3
03/02/2018 .......   ......
03/02/2018 .......   ......
03/02/2018 .......   ......
04/02/2018 .......   ......
04/02/2018 .......   ......
05/02/2018 .......   ......
05/02/2018 .......   ......

table2
column4     column5   column6
03/02/2018  .......   .......
04/02/2018  .......   .......
05/02/2018  .......   .......
```

here is what I would like to do

```
table1
column1    column2   column3  column4   column5   column6
03/02/2018 .......   ......
03/02/2018 .......   ......
03/02/2018 .......   ......   .......    ......   .......  <= same date 
04/02/2018 .......   ......
04/02/2018 .......   ......   .......    ......   .......  <= same date
05/02/2018 .......   ......
05/02/2018 .......   ......   .......    ......   .......  <= same date
```

thanks!

Comment: Insert has the meaning of adding rows to a table. Is this what you want or a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to just want a `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.column5, t2.column6
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.column1 = t2.column4;
```

I don't see value in actually *adding* these columns to the table.  With both tables in the same database and indexes on the `join` columns, the performance for running the query should be fine.

If you really want to update `table1`, you need to start by altering the table to have the new columns (which can be an expensive operation) and then updating the values in the columns.